# Stanford CoreNLP how to get IndexedWord from CoreLabel?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm running a few sentences through a Stanford pipeline that includes the "tokenize", "ssplit", and "parse" options. The CoreLabel is from the list of tokens in the sentence. Given such a CoreLabel, is there a way to get the corresponding IndexedWord in the SemanticGraph?

I ask because I'm using both the SyntaxTree and Dependency annotations. I have an algorithm that gets the main verb using the syntax tree. I then want to get the subject using Dependency annotations. Please let me know if there's a better way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, `IndexedWord` has a constructor that takes a `CoreLabel`. Though, this will only work if the CoreLabel already has an Index annotation attached (e.g., if it came from an indexed word to begin with).

Comment: IndexedWord does have such a constructor. However, when I construct an IndexedWord with the CoreLabel, the identity information (i.e. string representation, part of speech) is copied, but the Dependency relations are not. Thus I can't get the sentence subject with the new IndexedWord. I was expecting that maybe the CoreLabel would store some of the Dependency information, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Wait, IndexedWord doesn't store dependency information either... If you have an associated dependency tree somewhere, and a CoreLabel that at some point came from that dependency tree, you should be able to look up the dependency relations. Otherwise, you're dealing with the CoreLabel equals() function, and have to be careful.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but to look up relations you need an `IndexedWord`. The `CoreLabel` did not come directly from the dependency tree, but it seems that it's the backing label of some `IndexedWord`. Theoretically there should be some way to use the CoreLabel to query dependencies, but I haven't found anything in the API that allows me to do that.

Comment: So, if you know the index of the word you're looking up, and you have the original sentence, you can do something like `new IndexedWord(sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class).get(i), i)` and then look up the dependencies that way?

Comment: `IndexedWord` doesn't seem to have a constructor that takes a `CoreLabel` and an int. I'm using version 3.6.0.

Comment: Oh, weird... Well, you should be able to use `new IndexedWord(sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class).get(i))` too. Maybe a code snippet would help debug?

Comment: The dependency tree will be stored as a `SemanticGraph`, which defines the method `getNodeByIndex(int i)`. So if you have a `CoreLabel label` and a `SemanticGraph sg`, you can call `sg.getNodeByIndex(label.index())` and you should get the corresponding `IndexedWord`.

Comment: Sebastian Schuster, Gabor Angeli thank you both for your help. Sebastian's comment gave what I wanted to get. Can one of you post an answer for it? Thanks.